# What is the joint distribution of $W_t$ and $\int_0^t W_s \,ds$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

The following question is taken from Mark Joshi's Quant Job Interview.

> Question: What is the joint distribution of $W_t$ and $I(t)$ where $(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is Brownian motion and 
>   $$I(t) = \int_0^t W_s \,ds?$$

When one wants to find joint density, one can start at joint CDF followed by partial differentiation with respect to each random variable.

In this case, however, we have 
$$P(W_t \leq x, I(t) \leq y).$$
I do not know how to evaluate the probability above.

If they are independent, then I know how to evaluate the product as each of the random variable follows a normal distribution.

Comment: Hint: They are joint Gaussian, and each has mean zero, so it suffices to find their variances and covariance.  Fubini's theorem will be useful for this.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, indeed.